# Azure pipeline has stopped requiring user approval

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use Azure pipelines to deploy to different environments (dev, test, prod) that have been running for 2 1/2 years without issue.

Recently the pipeline has stopped asking for 'approval' after the test deployment stage.

It has been working with the following steps for 2.5 years

1. Build
2. Deploy to 'dev' without approval
3. Wait for manual approval
4. Deploy to 'test'
5. Wait for manual approval
6. Deploy to 'prod'

The Azure pipeline is a template within a separate repo - there have been no changes to the .yaml files but now the process is

1. Build
2. Deploy to 'dev' without approval
3. Wait for manual approval
4. Deploy to 'test'
5. Deploy to 'prod'

This behaviour is mirrored on every service that deploys using this template.

I am at a loss as to what is causing this

Answer (score 0):

The solution was this:

I 'environment' production had lost its approval - adding it back did not work.

So deleted and recreated and excepted the loss of deployment history. Working now.

Why this would happen I do not not know